# Create zip package on mac in RStudio

Tags: r, package, libraries

Is there a way to create r source packages in zip format on mac OS in RStudio? If so how to do that?

When I am trying to build a source package `devtools::build()` I am left with tar.gz file. Why not zip? How to force it to create zip?

Anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for `zip` (de-)compression in the `tar` utility, which `build()` uses to bundle the package, and is used when installing a package. Depending on what version you have it can compress with `gzip`, `bzip2` and `compress` algorithms on old versions, and `lzma`, `lzop`, `xz` and `lzip` on newer GNU versions.

Hence making a `tar.zip` archive would make little sense, as the standard ways of unpacking and installing it would not work.

Comment: OK, understood nevertheless there is no possibility to create it whatsoever when building source package?

Comment: @mkropkowski: Short of decompressing the `tar.gz` and recompress it using zip, no.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help!